# Error in deploying airflow by kubectl+kubeadm+helm+caiico cni

Tags: kubernetes, helm, kubectl, kubeadm, apache-airflow

**Description** 
I installed airflow from offical kubectl, kubeadm, helm, calico cni website but airflow can't be deployed.

**Tried**
Install kubectl, kubeadm, helm from offical website.
Install calico cni from [offical website](https://docs.tigera.io/calico/latest/getting-started/kubernetes/self-managed-onprem/onpremises).

Create airflow namespace

```
kubectl create namespace airflow
```

Install airflow with Helm

```
helm repo add apache-airflow https://airflow.apache.org
helm install airflow apache-airflow/airflow --namespace airflow --debug --timeout 30m0s
```

My pods status

```
NAME                                   READY   STATUS     RESTARTS        AGE
airflow-postgresql-0                   0/1     Pending    0               31m
airflow-redis-0                        0/1     Pending    0               31m
airflow-run-airflow-migrations-mmf66   1/1     Running    1 (9m57s ago)   31m
airflow-scheduler-7b7c797965-k9lt9     0/2     Init:0/1   1 (9m57s ago)   31m
airflow-statsd-5667dd85ff-92rlj        1/1     Running    0               31m
airflow-triggerer-0                    0/2     Pending    0               31m
airflow-webserver-697c65fcd9-4l9d6     0/1     Init:0/1   1 (9m57s ago)   31m
airflow-worker-0                       0/2     Pending    0               31m
```

Just `airflow-run-airflow-migrations-mmf66` and `airflow-statsd-5667dd85ff-92rlj` running.

The remaining pods do not run even though I have set the timeout to 30m.

Error in `airflow-postgresql-0`

```
Volumes:
  data:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  data-airflow-postgresql-0
    ReadOnly:   false
  dshm:
    Type:       EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:     Memory
    SizeLimit:  <unset>
  kube-api-access-68ktd:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   Burstable
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age    From               Message
  ----     ------            ----   ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  3m41s  default-scheduler  0/3 nodes are available: pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims. preemption: 0/3 nodes are available: 3 Preemption is not helpful for scheduling.
```

Error in `airflow-redis-0`

```
Volumes:
  redis-db:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  redis-db-airflow-redis-0
    ReadOnly:   false
  kube-api-access-b7zpv:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   BestEffort
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age                From               Message
  ----     ------            ----               ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  56s (x5 over 18m)  default-scheduler  0/3 nodes are available: pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims. preemption: 0/3 nodes are available: 3 Preemption is not helpful for scheduling.
```

Default pvcs when installing airflow

```
NAME                        STATUS    VOLUME   CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   VOLUMEATTRIBUTESCLASS   AGE
data-airflow-postgresql-0   Pending                                                     <unset>                 55m
logs-airflow-triggerer-0    Pending                                                     <unset>                 55m
logs-airflow-worker-0       Pending                                                     <unset>                 55m
redis-db-airflow-redis-0    Pending                                                     <unset>                 55m
```

Error `data-airflow-postgresql-0`

```
Name:          data-airflow-postgresql-0
Namespace:     airflow
StorageClass:  
Status:        Pending
Volume:        
Labels:        app.kubernetes.io/component=primary
               app.kubernetes.io/instance=airflow
               app.kubernetes.io/name=postgresql
Annotations:   <none>
Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
Capacity:      
Access Modes:  
VolumeMode:    Filesystem
Used By:       airflow-postgresql-0
Events:
  Type    Reason         Age                   From                         Message
  ----    ------         ----                  ----                         -------
  Normal  FailedBinding  114s (x202 over 52m)  persistentvolume-controller  no persistent volumes available for this claim and no storage class is set
```

I expected pods that must run!

Thanks for help!